# Compare a wchar string from a vector with an other specified wchar string

Tags: c++, c, vector, bluetooth, wchar

**@pmr**: Look at the code below

**@singeroftheall**: I have with both things problems. Inserting and searching. I think the searching part is done. Now how can I insert my mac adresses in the vector ?
My Adresses are saved in the varable m_device_info.Adress.rgBytes[]; See below.

```
    wprintf(L"\t\tAddress: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\r\n", m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5]);
```

It is possible to mix the languages C and C++ ? Cause the vector output is in c++ ?

==================================================================================
I have written a code which shows me all available Bluetooth devices. I just want to save all the MAC addresses (Type: `wchar`) of the available devices in a vector list. After that I want to search for an specified `wchar`, if is it in the vector list.

I am not a pro programmer in c/c++ and just need this to compare thing for a demonstration and look whether my idea is working. I would be very glad and happy, if somebody can help me. I also searched google and written in other faqs, but didn't find a good solution which helps me.

**CODE for searching Devices:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <bthdef.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "Irprops.lib")

BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS m_bt_find_radio = {
    sizeof(BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS)
};

BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO m_bt_info = {
    sizeof(BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO),
    0
};

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS m_search_params = {
    sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
    1,
    0,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    15,
    NULL
};

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO m_device_info = {
    sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO),
    0
};

HANDLE m_radio = NULL;
HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND m_bt = NULL;
HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND m_bt_dev = NULL;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **args) {
    while(true) {
        m_bt = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio);
        int m_radio_id = 0;
        do {
            m_radio_id++;

            BluetoothGetRadioInfo(m_radio, &m_bt_info);

            wprintf(L"Radio %d:\r\n", m_radio_id);
            wprintf(L"\tName: %s\r\n", m_bt_info.szName);
            wprintf(L"\tAddress: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\r\n", m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[1], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[0], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[2], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[3], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[4], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[5]);
            wprintf(L"\tClass: 0x%08x\r\n", m_bt_info.ulClassofDevice);
            wprintf(L"\tManufacturer: 0x%04x\r\n", m_bt_info.manufacturer);

            m_search_params.hRadio = m_radio;

            ::ZeroMemory(&m_device_info, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));
            m_device_info.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);

            m_bt_dev = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&m_search_params, &m_device_info);

            vector <string> macadresse;
            int n;
            int m_device_id = 0;
            do {
                m_device_id++;
                wprintf(L"\tDevice %d:\r\n", m_device_id);
                wprintf(L"\t\tName: %s\r\n", m_device_info.szName);
                wprintf(L"\t\tAddress: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\r\n", m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5]);
                wprintf(L"\t\tClass: 0x%08x\r\n", m_device_info.ulClassofDevice);

                //devicemc[m_device_id]= m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5];
                //macadresse.push_back(string (&m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0], &m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], &m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2], &m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], &m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], &m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5]));

            } while(BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, &m_device_info));
            BluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev);

        } while(BluetoothFindNextRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio));
        BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt);
        Sleep(10000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you cut the code down your actual problem? None of the bluetooth stuff seems related.

Comment: Do you have a problem in inserting strings inside a vector? Or just with searching for some string _in_ the vector?

Comment: I think you are on the right track. If you use `wchar_t` you should also use `wstring` and `vector<wstring>`.

Comment: I have with both things problems. The searching thing is resolved I think. But how can I insert it now ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The characters in a `string` are not of type `wchar`, but `char`. You probably need a `vector<wstring>`. To search for some `wstring` in a `vector`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<wstring> vec;
// insert something
vec.push_back(wstring("my_string"));

// search something
vector<wstring>::iterator it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), wstring("needle"));
if(it != vec.end()) {
  cout << "Found it" << '\n';
} else {
  cout << "Not found" << '\n';
}
```

Comment: **@pmr**: Look at the code below

**@singeroftheall**: I have with both things problems. Inserting and searching. I think the searching part is done. Now how can I insert my mac adresses in the vector ?
My Adresses are saved in the varable m_device_info.Adress.rgBytes[]; See below.

  wprintf(L"\t\tAddress: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\r\n", m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5]);

Comment: @user1557170 I added the necessary includes and an example of insertion. Please don't edit comments into answers. Use comments. Also, please have a look at SO faq to get to know the site.